# bestway to animate a Label, button or textfield

Tags: codenameone

I want a TextArea background alternate with its inverse when an alarm condition exists every second.
Other than alternating UIID's is there a better more pragmatic approach?

Comment: If you have an example of the effect I can help more, you can use style animations, container.replace() with face or another transition. There are plenty of ways to produce effects and each has use cases so none of them are "best"

Comment: Have a textbox with black foreground and black background. I want to alternate their inverse by setting the foreground = background and reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
while(animating) {
   ComponentAnimation ca = cmp.createStyleAnimation("Highlighted", 150);
   cmp.getAnimationManager().addAnimationAndBlock(ca);
   ca = cmp.createStyleAnimation("OriginalUIID", 150);
   cmp.getAnimationManager().addAnimationAndBlock(ca);
}
```